# How to create a tabbed Joptionpane for multiple data input

Tags: java, swing, input, joptionpane, dialog

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make a Tabbed Joptionpane for user input. Basically I need to take multiple values from user input, but instead of multiplied dialog boxes, I would like them to be able to enter all the separate data into one box. Is this possible? I can't seem to figure it out. In Java btw.

Comment: Show us what did you tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple input in JOptionPane.showInputDialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555040/multiple-input-in-joptionpane-showinputdialog)

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom JOptionPane. Basically you define a JPanel that will contain the input fields, and organize this panel as you want. See : [Multiple input in JOptionPane.showInputDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555040/multiple-input-in-joptionpane-showinputdialog)

Comment: This is a comment and marks this question as a possible duplicate question and should be closed...