# In java is there anyway to prompt one user input box that can create an object and that prompts the user to input all accompanying variables?

Tags: java, eclipse, joptionpane, windowbuilder

I am designing a simple payroll program in which I wish to prompt the user to add an employee object. The employee has several attributes

> Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String address, String phoneNum, int employeeIdNum, double wageRate, double hours);

JOptionPane allows me to create separate input prompt windows for each individual variable but that is a lot of windows. I am trying to encompass all the information in one window so the user may fill in all 7 variables without having to hit ok/continue 7 times.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555040/multiple-input-in-joptionpane-showinputdialog

Comment: then i would suggest not using Joptionpane and instead a Dialog/JFrame with a nicer layout of all components

Comment: You can do it with a JOptionPane. The 'message' argument of the 'showInputDialog()' methods can be a JPanel with multiple input text fields in it.

Answer (score 0):

*(Not an out-of-the-box solution)*

There does exist the [BeanInfo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/beaninfo.html) API to do just that: adding for any java bean, POJO, a BeanInfo that lists properties. It is used in several IDEs, GUI builders to have components with a property table.

Stand-alone you will need your own component: a JTable with two/three columns, the first a read-only field name, the second an editor for the value, and later maybe a third column for som edit icon.

Such a component can be shown for instance in a custom JOptionPane.