# JOptionPane take arraylist of objects?

Tags: java, swing

I have an ArrayList that has many objects. For example:

```
ArrayList<Supplier> a = new ArrayList<>();
```

As you see it's an ArrayList from type `Supplier` which is a class that has 4 attributes (name, company, address, phone number)

```
public class Supplier {
    public String name;
    public String company;
    public String address;
    public String phone_no;
}
```

I want to write `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` statement that shows the list elements in a drop down list to choose one of them and after taking the choice I want to divide that choice into 4 attributes again from the same class.

This is my code, but it didn't work:

```
String []choices = null;
for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    choices[i] = a.get(i).toString();
}
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose supplier of the product !!", "Select Supplier", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null, choices, "----");
```

Comment: can you please explain in a more clear way ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555040/multiple-input-in-joptionpane-showinputdialog   -   Multiple fields

Comment: Well again.... this array list take many objects of class `Supplier` .. well... i want to print object elements to be showed in drop down list ... for example like this: `John Pepsi London 9584841` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use something like this:

```
  ArrayList<Supplier> a = new ArrayList<>();

 String[] choices = a.toArray();

  String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose now...",
    "Choose supplier of the product !!", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,                                                                     
    choices, // Array of choices
    choices[1]); // Initial choice
```

Comment: The best solution ... thanks :)

Comment: @MHM This "best solution" is neither usable nor compilable.

Comment: Btw: what I meant with "not usable or compilable": the latest change with `String[] choices = a.toArray();` won't work.

Comment: @Tom its edited in the post, before edit there were normal array of strings so i apply this idea on my code posted in the answer and its work.

Comment: @MHM Yes, the older version was working, but this is one is now broken :P.

Answer (score 1):

The array you are using is not initialized causing `NullPointerException`.

Use the below code

```
String[] choices = a.toArray();
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose supplier of the product !!",
            "Select Supplier", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, choices,
            "----");
```

Also update the toString() method in Supplier class as below:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Supplier [name=" + name + ", company=" + company + ", address="
            + address + ", phone_no=" + phone_no + "]";
}
```

Keep the fields that you need to show in the dropdown.

Comment: this print the address of the objects stored ... i want the object values.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Abdelhak answer i tried this and worked for me:

First assume that array list has already some values so we use iterator to loop faster in array list then i used for loop inside iterator to initialize array of strings.

```
        Iterator<Supplier> i = a.iterator();
        String []choices = new String[a.size()];
        while(i.hasNext())
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++)
            {
                Supplier p = i.next();
                choices[j] = p.getName() + " " + p.getCompany() + " " + p.getAddress() + " " + p.getPhone_no();
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose supplier of the product !!", "Select Supplier", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null, choices, "----");
```

Comment: @Abdelhak please check this

Comment: does this code give you some issue

Comment: I can't understand why are add these lines: Supplier p = i.next();
     choices[j] = p.getName() + " " + p.getCompany() + " " + p.getAddress() + " " + p.getPhone_no();

Comment: @Abdelhak Because his `Supplier` class doesn't has a proper `toString` implementation. That is why he chose this way to get a String representation of his `Supplier` instance.

Comment: @Abdelhak well, iterator is a good thing to loop faster in array list .. it is more faster than normal for loop ... and we just use for loop to initialize the array of strings .... its working perfect with me :) ... the same idea of your solution.

Comment: @MHM There is no significant performance difference between these two approaches: [Which is more efficient, a for-each loop, or an iterator?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2113216). Edit: oh you wrote "normal" for loop. Well, you're using an `ArrayList`, so there is also no difference here, but I would suggest to use the enhanced `for` loop instead. Easier to write and to read.