# Java remove lines from file

Tags: java

I am trying to delete a line in a file based on 2 parts in the line: the book title and its ID. I want the user to enter both and if they are both in a line, delete the line. This is the code I have however the only problem is that `removeLine` says "cannot convert from int to string".
Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
          File inFile = new File("books.txt");

          if (!inFile.isFile()) {

            return;
          }


          File tempFile = new File("books.txt" + "1");

          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
          PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

          String line = null;



          JTextField xField = new JTextField(10);
            JTextField yField = new JTextField(10);

            JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
            myPanel.add(new JLabel("Title:"));
            myPanel.add(xField);
            myPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15)); // a spacer
            myPanel.add(new JLabel("ID:"));
            myPanel.add(yField);

            String removeLine = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel,
                "Remove", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            if (removeLine == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {



          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!line.trim().contains(removeLine)) {
              pw.println(line);
              pw.flush();
            }
          }

          pw.close();
          br.close();

          //Delete the original file
          if (!inFile.delete()) {
            System.out.println("Could not delete file");
            return;
          } 

          //Rename the new file to the filename the original file had.
          if (!tempFile.renameTo(inFile)) {
            System.out.println("Could not rename file");
          }
```

Comment: *Just in case anyone was wondering I did try and change removeLine to int but then the contains(removeLine) gives me the error "the method contains (CharSequence) in the type string is not applicable for the argument int"

Comment: I think that your solution is explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555040/multiple-input-in-joptionpane-showinputdialog You don't recover the values introduced by the user from xField and yField. removeLine will contain only JOptionPane.OK_OPTION or JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION and not the book to be removed

Answer (score -1):

`JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog` returns an int not a String, so you should change the type of removeLine to int.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I already tried that but then the contains(lineToRemove) does not work because "the method contains (CharSequence) in the type string is not applicable for the argument int"

Comment: You need to use a different method in order to get the text they submitted, `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog` will only give you whether or not they have confirmed.

You should do this as follows. You need to store the ID and title they entered by getting `xField.getText()` and `yField.getText()`. Then, check if both of these are in the line separately.

Comment: I am able to use a showInputDialog but it gives me 3 boxes. 2 boxes for the xField and yField and one large box that basically does nothing.