# How do I get a specific responce when a JOptionPane is shut down by the cross in the upper right corner

Tags: java, swing

Due to JOptionPanes being almost unusably buggy I tend to often get grey and empty panes which I close down by pressing the upper right corner.
When I do this the panes returns an anser Yes or No to my code whichI obviously do not want. How can I get my JOptionPanes to understand that it should reload the panel when I close it down?

Comment: "...JOptionPanes being almost unusably buggy.." No they are not buggy. Maybe you are using them wrong. Post some code that reproduces your problems.

Comment: Well at least they are highly random when they work and when they dont... Im atleast looking for a way arounf this feature of randomness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the [`JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-) methods like they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6555051/261156) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3002830/261156). The default `optionType` is *Yes, No, Cancel*, and the result will be `CANCEL_OPTION` if you click the winbdow's close button. If you're getting empty panes just *sometimes*, be sure to use the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) from the begining of your program.